# Change timezone without tzutil - Windows Web Server 2008

Tags: windows

For some reason Web does not include tzutil. You must have R2 to access this utility.

This is frustrating because I need to change the time according to different timezones.

How can I use the "time" command to change the time based on an input timezone (like GMT-6 or possibly "Central Standard Time") ?

Comment: What version is the operating system for the machine in question?

Comment: Windows Web Server 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Vista and Server 2008 RTM did not ship with a way to change time zones via script.  Microsoft fixed this by releasing [KB2556308](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2556308).  This hotfix will give you the TZUtil command-line tool.

Comment: When I try to install I get "This update does not apply to your system"

Comment: A couple of things to watch out for: First, the hotfix only applies to 2008 RTM or SP2; it doesn't appear to support SP1 (so you'll need to upgrade the service pack if that is the case).  Second, make sure you're running the correct version of the hotfix.  If you're like me, you're downloading the file from your workstation to move to the server. Microsoft tries to "detect" which version you need based on the calling machine. Be sure to select "Show hotfixes for all platforms and languages" to see all of the versions and pick the correct one based on your sever type.